# Avoid showing big number inside html card

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have [image] this card here and i am showing dynamic data inside it. As you can see the number is too large so i want the number to show like this `0.600000+` and then if i hover onto it then a tooltip shows me the full number. How can i do this?

Here is the html code for this card

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">               
 <div class="info-box bg-teal hover-expand-effect">
  <div class="icon">
   <a [routerLink]="['/app/home']">
    <i class="material-icons">attach_money</i>
   </a>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
   <div class="text" (mouseenter) ="mouseEnter() " >Upcoming Bill</div>
    <div class="number">${{upcomingEstimatedBill}}</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular has some build in Pipes, and one of them transforms your number into a proper currency format. Just add the following:

```
...
<div class="number">{{upcomingEstimatedBill | currency: 'USD'}}</div>
...
```

Alternatively it is very easy to build your own pipe to transform the number any way you want.